# SDS, SDS MAX, SDS PLUS: which bits can I use?

Tags: tools

I recently purchased two Dewalt D25501K Hammer Drills.  I need bits.  In pest control doing termite treatments, we need to drill 1/2 inch holes through concrete slabs. In the past I have used drills that have had "spline" drives. These Dewalts don't, so I am uneducated on what bits I need.  I know I need 1/2 inch in diameter and at least 16 inches or so cutting depth, but I'm not sure if my new drills require a certain kind of SDS bit. I see SDS MAX, SDS PLUS and just SDS. Can you tell me what my drills can and will use so I know what to buy?

Comment: Related: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11452/what-are-the-differences-between-sds-sds-plus-and-sds-max-drills

Answer (score 2):

It's described as SDS MAX and Spline combination.

This question/answer imply that your choices are... SDS MAX and Spline. SDS MAX is incompatible with (and much larger than) the other SDS types.

[What are the differences between SDS, SDS Plus, and SDS Max drills?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11452/what-are-the-differences-between-sds-sds-plus-and-sds-max-drills)

Answer (score 0):

You need SDS Max. (SDS Plus, sometimes just called SDS, is smaller and won't fit.) For what it's worth, I've had good luck with Bosch and Dewalt SDS bits.